# Bash - variable in the process

Tags: bash

I wrote a script:

Old script:

```
var="$(sleep 5 && echo "Linux is...")" &
sleep 5
echo $var
```

New script:

```
var="$(cat file | grep Succeeded && kilall cat)" & killer1=$!
(sleep 60; kill $killer1) & killer2=$!
fg 1
kill $killer2
echo $var
```

Cat file works all the time. Should return "... \n Succeeded \n ...". Echo empty always returns. Is there a solution? I want to necessarily result in a variable.

Comment: Why are you using a sleep when you assign var? Are you trying to delay assignment or something?

Comment: Is this in a script or are you typing this at a prompt? Also note that each line is executed in order.

Comment: The new script is very confusing. What are you trying to do? Killer combat unit? Also note that fg is not possible to use in script.

Answer (score 1):

When you terminate a command by `&`, the shell executes the command in a subshell. `var` is set in the subshell, not the original process.

Answer (score 1):

If you run it on the background using &, it is in separate process, so you no more share variables. You need to use IPC (interprocess comunication) to assure this. Easiest IPC to use is a pipe:

```
{ sleep 2 && echo 'Linux is ...' ; } | 
{ 
echo 'doing something here in the meantime...'
sleep 1
read var 
echo $var
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `&` from the assignment of var (line 1 in your script).